# How to properly generate a list from other two lists according to a condition in Flutter

Tags: list, flutter

I am trying to generate a list called selectedBooks based on other two lists:

This is the first list:

```
    List<Book> availableBooks = [
       Book(
        id: 1,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 1"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 2,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 2"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 3,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 3"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 4,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 4"
       ),
    ]
```

This is the second list:

```
    List<Book> allowedBooks = [
       Book(
        id: 1,
        isActive: true,
        name: "Tipo 1"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 3,
        isActive: true,
        name: "Tipo 3"
       ),
    ]
```

And this is the list I'm trying to generate:

```
       selectedBooks = availableBooks
          .map((book) =>
              allowedBooks.contains(book.id)
                  ? Book(
                      id: book.id,
                      isActive: true,
                      name: book.name)
                  : Book(
                      id: book.id,
                      isActive: false,
                      name: book.name))
          .toList();
```

Since allowedBooks does contain id 1 and 3, I am expecting selectedBooks to be:

```
    List<Book> selectedBooks = [
       Book(
        id: 1,
        isActive: true,
        name: "Tipo 1"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 2,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 2"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 3,
        isActive: true,
        name: "Tipo 3"
       ),
       Book(
        id: 4,
        isActive: false,
        name: "Tipo 4"
       ),
    ]
```

However, this doesn't work because selectedBooks ends up having all book.isActive set to false.

I assume something is not working as expected in the condition here included:

```
selectedBooks = availableBooks
          .map((book) =>
              allowedBooks.contains(book.id) ? ...
```

Any clue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you have [operator==](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Object/operator_equals.html) overriden in `Book` class? it it used by [contains](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/Iterable/contains.html) method

Comment: Hi @pskink, no it's not overridden.

Comment: @pskink I use the operator == elsewhere, so I don't think I should override it. Can I change the condition to achieve the result in a different way, in your opinion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `allowedBooks.contains(book.id)` you should use `allowedBooks.any((allowedBook) => allowedBook.id == book.id)`

Answer (score 0):

`contains` compares whole object, try this way

```
 List<Book> selectedBooks = availableBooks
          .map((book) => allowedBooks.singleWhere((it) => it.id == book.id, 
          orElse: () => null) != null ? Book(
                      id: book.id,
                      isActive: true,
                      name: book.name) : Book(
                      id: book.id,
                      isActive: false,
                      name: book.name)).toList();
```

Tested in [dartpad.dev](https://dartpad.dev/cbb548fc17366b423020dd17ad4c581b?)